# Good initialization scheme for arrays involved in creating a mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, initialization

To be honest, I was not able to come up with a good title for this question. Anyhow, here is the problem. I have 3 arrays that are used based on a query. If the query consists of some elements that are `None`, the corresponding array is not used.

```py
query = {
    "a": None,
    "b": ">5",
    "c": "<10"
}

A = query["a"]
B = query["b"][1:]
C = query["c"][1:]

# initialization scheme?
a_arr = ...
b_arr = ...
c_arr = ...

# use arrays based on query
if query["a"] != None:
    a_arr = ["aa", "bb", "aab", "bba", "aabb"]

if query["b"] != None:
    b_arr = [1,3,6,2,9,10]

if query["c"] != None:
    c_arr = [7,4,2,12,60,22,49]
```

Now, I have to create a mask based on the truth value of above arrays. Something like this:

```py
mask = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(a_arr == A, b_arr > int(B)), c_arr < int(C))
```

How do I initialize the arrays `a_arr`, `b_arr`, and `c_arr` so that the resulting mask is not affected if one or more of the values in the query is `None`?

Comment: I do not fully understand, but given that ```x_arr``` is a an array of which values you want from ```A```, ```B``` and ```C```. You could get the mask by using ```np.isin(A, x_arr)```. If you want them to be based on the left operand ```x_arr``` you just need to flip the order: ```np.isin(x_arr, A)```. Taking intersection of multiple masks (```a_arr```, ```b_arr``` and ```c_arr```) is just multiplication (which is effectively the same as doing ```np.logical_and```.

Comment: `x_arr` will be a computed array e.g `a_arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`. The conditional check `a_arr = A` e.g will return `[True, False, False, False, False]` and similarly for other arrays `b_arr` and `c_arr` with `B` and `C` respectively. The problem is I want to compute the mask using the statement above without writing several `if, elif` statements. Basically, the boolean arrays resulting from the conditional check should be `True` whenever the corresponding query element is `None`. I hope it clarifies the question!

Comment: Do you want to compute ```a_arr```, ```b_arr``` and ```c_arr``` without using the if statements?

Comment: No, I just want a good initialization scheme that doesn't affect the resulting `mask` boolean array. The `if` statements in the first block are required

Comment: @Kevin Sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question which now more clearly explains the problem. Meanwhile, I also came up with a solution (posted below).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that is not the most elegant but works in my case. Instead of initializing the arrays `a_arr`, `b_arr`, and `c_arr`, I initialize the truth value of `x_arr op X`. If any of the query values are not `None`, it sets the truth value again. This works because a statement `True and a` evaluates to `a`. I am posting the whole snippet here in case anyone wants to reproduce the results.

```py
query = {
    "a": None,
    "b": ">5",
    "c": "<10"
}

A = query["a"]
B = query["b"][1:]
C = query["c"][1:]

# evaluate truth values of array

a_truth = True
if A != None:
    a_arr = ["aa", "bb", "aab", "bba", "aabb"]
    a_truth = a_arr == A

b_truth = True
if B != None:
    b_arr = [1,3,6,2,9,10]
    b_truth = b_arr > int(B)

c_truth = True
if C != None:
    c_arr = [7,4,2,12,60,22,49]
    c_truth = c_arr < int(C)

mask = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(a_truth, b_truth), c_truth)
```

Thank you for your time!